# Why is tortoise-git changing my file permissions?

Tags: windows, cygwin, git, tortoise-git

I switch between using tortoise git and cmd line git on cygwin very frequently, and lately I've noticed that when I `git status` via cygwin and no changes are found, then I go to use tortoise git, and right click on a repo then use the "Git Commit -> ..." menu item, I get a list of files that have supposedly changed, but of course when review the diff there are no changes to the file contents, it's actually the file permissions which appear to be changed, which git via cygwin does not recognize.

So what is wrong with my tortoise git setup?

Comment: What have the permissions changed from and to?

Comment: well the mode seems to change back and forth between mode 100644 to 100755, not sure how this corresponds to permissions, I just assumed it is.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257592/removing-files-saying-old-mode-100755-new-mode-100644-from-unstaged-changes-in) looks similar, but I don't know how to change the core.filemode to false..

Comment: Related: [Git file permissions on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6476513/3258851) (Stack Overflow)

Comment: Also [How do I remove files saying “old mode 100755 new mode 100644” from unstaged changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1257592/3258851)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$ git config core.filemode false
```

Read the documentation on [git config](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).

add --global to set it over all of your git projects.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that TortoiseGit and Git Gui don't handle the x bit on Windows as well as cygwin does. Most people probably don't care about changing the x bit, so "core.filemode false" is a good solution to keep both cygwin and your GUI happy.